# Match beginning and end of string with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to pull the parsable-cite info from this [webpage](http://deepbills.cato.org/api/1/bill?congress=113&billnumber=499&billtype=s&billversion=is) using python. For example, for the page listed I would pull pl/111/148 and pl/111/152. My current regex is listed below, but it seems to return everything after parsable cite. It's probably something simple, but I'm relatively new to regexes. Thanks in advance.

```
re.findall(r'^parsable-cite=.*>$',page)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend to use this regex which will capture what you want:

```
re.findall(r'parsable-cite=\\\"(.*?)\\\"\>',page)
```

explanation:

```
parsable-cite= matches the characters parsable-cite= literally (case sensitive)
  \\ matches the character \ literally
  \" matches the character " literally
  1st Capturing group (.*?)
  .*? matches any character (except newline)
      Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible,
           expanding as needed
  \\ matches the character \ literally
  \" matches the character " literally
  \> matches the character > literally
```

using **?** is the key ;)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make your regex lazy:

```
re.findall(r'^parsable-cite=.*?>$',page)
                              ^
```

Or use a negated class (preferable):

```
re.findall(r'^parsable-cite=[^>]*>$',page)
```

`.*` is greedy by default and will try to match as much as possible before concluding a match.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pZ7fW1)

If you want to get the parts you need only, you can use capture groups:

```
re.findall(r'^parsable-cite=([^>]*)>$',page)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/nV6cW6)

---

Though, from the layout of your webpage, it doesn't seem that you need the anchors (`^` and `$`) (unless the newlines were somehow removed on the site...)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think the greedy problem was part of it, but now I'm getting just an empty list returned for all three of your regexes ..any more ideas?

Comment: @user1153018 Maybe the last part of my answer applies then. Try removing the `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 1):

The `.*` you have there is "greedy", meaning it will match as much as it can, including any number of `>` characters and whatever comes after them.

If what you really want is "everything up to the next `>`" then you should say `[^>]*>` instead, meaning "any number of non-`>` characters, then a `>`".

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
(?<=parsable-cite=\\\")\w{2}\/\d{3}\/\d{3}
```

http://regex101.com/r/kE9uE3

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a json string where html is embedded inside, but you can still use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) for this purpose:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls);
tags = soup.findAll("external-xref", {"parsable-cite":re.compile("")})
for t in tags:
    print t['parsable-cite']
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work if its between `\"` delimiters

```
 #  \bparsable-cite\s*=\s*\"((?s:(?!\").)*)\"

 \b 
 parsable-cite
 \s* = \s* 
 \"
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?s:
           (?! \" )
           . 
      )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 \"
```

Or, just

```
 #  (?s)\bparsable-cite\s*=\s*\"(.*?)\"

 (?s)
 \b 
 parsable-cite
 \s* = \s* 
 \"
 ( .*? )                 # (1)
 \"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think it will be very similar each time:

```
re.findall(r"pl/\d+/\d+", page)
```